# Downloading images in background

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I need to download images of huge sizes. Even when my app goes to background the download needs to continue. I am using SD-Web Image frame work for handling the image download. It works fine but when app goes from background to foreground the download of image gets terminated.

Here is my code:

```
let completionblock : SDExternalCompletionBlock = { image, error, cacheType, 
imageURL in
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
    }

  imageThumbnail.sd_setImage(with: imagUrl, completed: completionblock)`
```

Comment: Where is this piece of code called? I suspect it's in a view controller lifecycle function that gets trigged when the view is displayed, hence the issue. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Seeing "when my app goes to background the download needs to continue" I am not sure you are aware of limitations of your application when in background. At some point operation will terminate. You might need to implement your own system to just improve what you are seeing. Check for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403953/ios-swift-download-lots-of-small-files-in-background

Answer (score 0):

when download finished ,UIImageView will call mainThread.
Views update need on mainThread.  so ,you need update thread.

```
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
```

on main